# In a Jupyter notebook, how can I scroll past the last cell?

Tags: ipython, geany

This is a simple ergonomics question. There's an option in the editor Geany than enables the user to scroll past the last line displayed. This allows the user to, for example, bring the last line of code up to eye-level on a vertically-oriented display.

How can I do something similar in a Jupyter notebook? I don't want my head pointed downward all the time. How can I scroll past the last cell?

I'd expect the result to be someway comparable to using the Chromium extension [More Page Space](https://github.com/LudwikJaniuk/MorePageSpace/releases/).

Answer (score 10):

I was just looking for the same feature. I'm not sure if there is an official solution, but you can accomplish something similar to what you want by customizing the css. Try adding the following block to `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`:

```
.end_space {
  height: 75vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @banjeremy! That's what I'm looking for! Great!

Comment: Thanks!! Any way to dynamically determine the number of lines that fit on a screen so that we don't have to set the height via a constant? Would be useful when switching screens.

Comment: Not sure about the number of lines but the `vh` unit is [equal to 1% of the height of the viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length). It should adjust as you resize your browser window.